# In AngularJS, what's the difference between $scope and the native context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm just starting to look at Angular, but having a hard time wrapping my head around the need for `$scope`. Javascript already has a concept of scope via the context (i.e. `this`) and allows programmers to inject that context on a function using `call` or `apply`.

Are there any differences between Angular's, `$scope`, and the keyword `this`?

If there is a difference, then what is the value of `this` within a controller or directive?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `$scope` is dependency injected, I suppose it's not as simple as calling a function with a context. But you can if fact use `this` as `$scope` with the `controller as` syntax in `ng-controller`. But `$scope` it's still injectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are not the same at all. The constructor is just an instantiated **new** ed  constructor (the function you wrote) created by the injector.

`$scope` is more conceptually related to the DOM. In that elements with `ng-controller` get that `$scope` and child elements do as well. If a child element with its own scope (controller/directive) had the same properties as the parent scope You wouldn't be able to access them. It also has all of the internal information angular uses in its digest loop (dirty checking/ data binding) like watches,events,etc. I'd have a read through [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

As for the `myCtrl as` syntax, this is nice but all it really does is put the controller instance onto the scope. With the name that you set.

eg `myCtrl as foo`  is [basically](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/06557aab44860baf3f121f3db424c5ede0764bf4/src/ng/controller.js#L85) `$scope.foo = myCtrlInstance;`. Which you are capable of doing in your controller as well.

Comment: I realized that I was mixing my concepts of context and scope, which caused a lot of my confusion. Especially around the need for dependency injection in JavaScript. Also, I didn't realize Controllers & Directives were object constructors. I read the articles you linked, then supplemented with some more Googling, which led me here, http://clubajax.org/javascript-scope-and-context-not-the-same-thing/ . 

Then things finally clicked for me. Dependency Injection in JS/Angular is just a way for the calling code to modify the scope. i.e wrapping up closures into an object passed in as a parameter.